# Random grid path generator

Tags: python, random, path, 2d-games

I have a grid consisting of passable and non-passable squares, and need to randomly generate a path. It needs to be something between a maze and a pac-man style map so it has multpile routes between the start and the end and be relatively open but still has dead ends. I've done some research and all I can find is a randomised depth-first search which would make a perfect maze, which I don't want. [Here's an example of the sort of path needed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tUVY.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

One way that could work is starting from either [Prim's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) or [Kruskal's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) algorithm, and modify the result. You could randomly remove walls to allow more solution, or randomly add walls (as long as they are not blocking the main path) to have blocked off sections like in your picture.

You could also modify the algorithm with random probability of different behavior, i.e. from Randomized Kruskal's you could change

```
If the cells divided by this wall belong to distinct sets:
```

to

```
If the cells divided by this wall belong to distinct sets or randint(1,10) < 2:
```

which would allow some cycles